# Estimation of the $\ell^2$-norm for a sequence $(a_n/n)_n$.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

If I have a sequence $\mathbf{a} = (a_n)_n \in \ell^2(\mathbb{R}^4)$, what can I say about the sequence $\mathbf{b} = (\tfrac{a_n}{n})_n$ in terms of $||\mathbf{a}||_{\ell^2}$? It is clear that $||\mathbf{b}||_{\ell^2} \leq ||\mathbf{a}||_{\ell^2}$. However, I need something like $||\mathbf{b}||_{\ell^2} \leq \epsilon ||\mathbf{a}||_{\ell^2}$, for example $\epsilon = 3/4$. Is that possible? Or in other words, is there a sharper bound than $||\mathbf{a}||_{\ell^2}$?. The only additional information I have is that $(n a_n)_n \in \ell^2(\mathbb{R}^4)$ and that $a_n \neq 0$ for at least one $n \geq 3$.

Answer (score 1):

In general you can't say much. Imagine $a_1 = A$ and $a_n=0$ for $n>1$. Then $\mathbf a = \mathbf b$ so a strict inequality on the norms does not hold.

You might look at some partial sum and give a bound based on that. For instance, for any $N$

$$\Vert \mathbf b \Vert^2 \leq \frac{1}{(N+1)^2}\left(\Vert \mathbf a \Vert^2- \sum_{k=1}^N |a_k|^2\right) +\sum_{k=1}^N |a_k|^2\,.$$

Comment: Thanks, clearly stated like this, the question is trivial. The question is part of a research problem and actually we can assume that $a_n \neq 0$ for at least one $n \geq 3$. Otherwise, I am done.